# Autocomplete TextBox from barcode

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

When I typed letters in textbox it automatically suggest the next word. But when I search for numbers my application is automatically closed.

```
try
{
    var code = from cod in conn.AppProducts
               select cod.ManufacturerBarcode;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(code.ToArray());
    txtCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    txtCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Error in Auto " + e);
}
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel no exception just automatically application close

Comment: So you never reach your `catch`? Then why do you think the issue is with this piece of code?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel When i use 'Name' it's working

Comment: 1.Remove `try ... catch` - you don't need it, it will hide useful information. 2. During debug session `Debug - Windows - Exception Settings` and check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

You could start by adding the following to Program.cs before your app starts:

```
Application.ThreadException += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(args.ToString());
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(args.ToString());
```

This might give you a stack trace instead of your program just closing

Comment: Same thing happen. it close automatically.

Comment: Can you put a Close handler on your Form and a break point in the close event? see if that gets hit?  Also put break points in the lamda for the events I linked (on the right side of the `=>`)